# Get data from MySQL that corresponds to a certain pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two mysql tables:

TABLE A

```
id  |  name  |  favorite
 1  |  John  |   4;1;2;
```

etc...

TABLE B

```
id  |  label  |  product
 1  |   game  |   Xbox
 2  |   game  |   Playstation
 3  |   game  |   Wii
```

expected result

TABLE C

```
 2  |   game  |    Playstation
 3  |   game  |    Wii
```

I need to get data that corresponds to favorite column ( data is separated by semi-column ) from TABLE A and ID row column from TABLE B

Is there any foreach loop in mysql that can do this type of queries?

Comment: Can you change you table design?

Comment: @juergend got any ideas?

Comment: The normalization is the key to solve this question. Do you know relations between TA and TB?

Answer (score 3):

Your table design is not normalized. Add a new table

```
user_favorites table
--------------------
user_id
product_id
```

Example data:

```
user_id   |   product_id
1         |    4
1         |    1
1         |    2
```

Then you can get the result you like with

```
select b.*
from tableb b
join user_favorites f on b.id = f.product_id
join tablea a on f.user_id = a.id
where a.name = 'john'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should normalize your table design.  Storing lists of things in a string is a very bad idea.  Relational databases have a great structure for storing lists of things -- it is called a *table* not a string.  And, it is even worse to store numeric ids as strings.

That said, sometimes one is stuck with an existing database.  You can do a join to get what you want:

```
select b.id, b.label, b.product
from tablea a join
     tableb b
     on find_in_set(b.id, replace(a.favorite, ';', ',')) > 0;
```

Comment: all good statements, I agree. I'll normalize my table instead